# Libc6 missing or wrong version

Tags: 12.04, dpkg

After my laptop shut down in the middle of an update, my ubuntu 12.04 installation is seriously messed up.

When starting Ubuntu, it complains " running in low-graphics mode, screen, graphic cards qnd input device settings could not be detected correctly " and i can only open the terminal. Next I tried:

```
apt-get -f install
```

This gives me an "Internal Error, No File name for libc6". I've tried a few more things but each time i run into errors:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This gives me "dependency problems, errors were encountered while processing libc6, libc6-dev ..

Most "interesting" error was the one i get when trying to configure libc6:

```
dpkg --configure libc6
```

This results in: **libc6:amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.5 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is in a different version (2.15-0ubuntu10.4)**

Any ideas how to solve this? Help would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT:** 
Output of **`sudo apt-get check`**
I get: "The following packages have unmet dependencies: cpp-4.6 : Depends: gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 ) but is not installed" And then the same for a whole bunch more packages g++4.6,gcc-4.6, gfortran-4.6 ...
BUT for libc6 it's different: libc6: breaks: libc6:i386 (!=2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 0ubuntu10.5 is installed –

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: I get:
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.6 : Depends: gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 ) but is not installed"
And then the same for a whole bunch more packages g++4.6,gcc-4.6, gfortran-4.6, libc6 ...

Comment: For libc6 it's different: libc6: breaks: libc6:i386 (!=2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 0ubuntu10.5 is installed

Comment: Done! I'll remember it

Comment: Please the output is important. Paste it unabridged, whole, as you get it..

Comment: Nevermind I will reinstall the whole thing..

Comment: I disagree with Seth, Braiam, Florian Diesch, Jorge Castro and guntbert. This IS reproducable as I have the exact same problem. Power Outage during an update caused the system to go into a infinite loop between libc6 and multiarch. Although maybe this should be reported as a bug instead of a question.